# Issue with node-gh, possibly node.js install in general

Tags: node.js, github-api

I am new to node.js development.  I recently installed npm/node.js and installed the node-gh application.

When I load it, I get the following errors:

````
gh [success] Authentication succeed.
gh [success] Writing GH config data: /Users/esteban/.gh.json

fs.js:665
  return binding.readdir(pathModule._makeLong(path));
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.32/lib/node_modules'
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:665:18)
    at Object.exports.getPlugins (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gh/lib/base.js:250:18)
    at exports.checkVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gh/lib/base.js:176:27)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gh/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:551:21
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gh/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:227:13
    at iterate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gh/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:134:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gh/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:145:25
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gh/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:229:17
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gh/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:556:34
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gh/lib/git.js:119:9
```
````

Is it possibe there is an issue with my path?  Thank you.

EDIT:  Code from 246 - 260 of /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gh/lib/base.js:

```
exports.getPlugins = function() {
    var nodeModulesPath = exports.getNodeModulesGlobalPath(),
        plugins;

    plugins = fs.readdirSync(nodeModulesPath).filter(function(plugin) {
        return plugin.substring(0, 3) === 'gh-';
    });

    return plugins;
};

exports.getPluginBasename = function(plugin) {
    return plugin && plugin.replace('gh-', '');
};
```

Comment: Check permissions on that folder and the files in it. Make sure the user you're running node as can see them.

Comment: Well I'm on OS X, I've tried to run the application as sudo as well with no luck...

Comment: Could you post your node code from the line where this stack trace is originating from? That may shine some light if this is not a permissions issue. I would also try npm-outdated to see if you have any modules that are out of date and make sure you're on the latest node in case this is a module conflict that may have been resolved already.

Comment: Here are lines 246 - 260 of /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gh/lib/base.js:

Comment: Looks like a [known issue](https://github.com/node-gh/gh/issues/293) with `node-gh`. It'll probably work if you don't use Homebrew to install Node, but just the regular Node installer.

Comment: Thank you.  I was mostly concerned that my node installation wasn't working properly.